# How to achieve 30 frames per second using Android SurfaceView?

Tags: android, surfaceview

I am looking for example code sample that shows how to achieve 30 frames per seconds using
Android [SurfaceView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html)? Assume each frame draws a circle starting at position x and y and each frame increments x and y by one.

Bonus question:
On top of above I want to overlay another View to display text content so that whatever graphics is being drawn shows underneath this text content. How this can be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a thread that does this 30 times a second:

1. Call SurfaceHolder.lockCanvas().
2. Draws into the Canvas (must completely redraw all pixels).
3. Call SurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost().

In fact if your thread just sits there doing that without trying to pause, it will be throttled to the frame rate of the screen.

You need to make sure that this thread is correctly synchronized with management of the surface view -- for example if the surface is changing or being destroyed, your code there should synchronize with the thread to make sure the thread stops running while this happens.

Of course this does mean that you are doing software rendering into the canvas.  Depending on what you are doing, this may be fine to give you 30fps animation.  If not, you'll need to use GLSurfaceView.  You may want to consider using that anyway, just because it takes care of the threading part for you.

Comment: Is it really the best way to do that?

Answer (score 6):

If you want high frame rates, you really need to read up on [GLSurfaceView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html). Under a normal surface view you are going to be at the mercy of the expense layout calculations and CPU centric rendering. With the GLSurfaceView you can offload that to the GPU and have a tight efficient control of layouts.

Comment: GLSurfaceView only accelerates drawing (because you use OpenGL to draw to it).  It doesn't not get rid of layout calculations...  in fact there should never be layout calculations happening during drawing, even drawing of the regular view hierarchy.

Comment: "It doesn't not get rid of layout calculations" - did I say it did? "there should never be layout calculations happening during drawing" - I didn't say that either did I? However, talking about **frame rates** usually means something is moving/changing which will affect layout calculations. If you are using a native layout manager this will be expensive.

Comment: If I use GLSurfaceView as opposed to SurfaceView , how much this would have impact on battery usage and what effect it would have on battery usage if the device has no GPU and CPU is doing all the legwork? End users do not care about CPU/GPU cycles but they do care about how much battery is being drained by the application. My goal is find the approach that would not put more than a reasonable load on the battery.

Comment: In general the GPU is going to be *much* easier on the battery (this is from experience). Granted, if the device is not GPU accelerated then performance will suffer but in practice I haven't run into any phones that aren't. Also, I think you can filter out devices that don't meet a minimum hardware requirement in the market.

Answer (score 3):

This maybe an old thread but I think this can help others. 
Here is a nice tutorial I found on using surfaceView:
http://www.droidnova.com/playing-with-graphics-in-android-part-i,147.html

And here is a nice article on how to implement game-loop which can help limiting the FPS to 30: 
http://www.koonsolo.com/news/dewitters-gameloop/

You can add text directly to your surfaceView if you like,
Here is an example

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    ...
    // Add text
    Paint paint = new Paint(); 
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setFakeBoldText(true);               // if you like bold
    paint.setShadowLayer(5, 5, 5, Color.GRAY); // add shadow
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE); 
    paint.setTextSize(30); 
    canvas.drawText("FPS: " + _fps, 10, 35, paint);             
}
```